# Retrolambda/Multimodule confusion

Tags: android, retrolambda

I am using [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) and some tests got me quite confused.

My understanding is:

- with retrolambda I can use some java8 language features (e.g. lambdas), but not java 8 classes: e.g. without any additional libraries, I cannot use the java8 streams: [HashSet<>.stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) is not available
- I write my code with java-8 features (lambdas). The source code is translated into java8-class files and then retrolambda kicks in and converts the java8-class files to java7-class files which can be executed on older Android version (e.g. Android 6)

So, I've built a small test-project to test my assumptions and there are some things I am not sure of. I hope someone can clarify.
Heres a [tag of my source code](https://github.com/tmtron/RetrolambdaMultimodule/tree/Retrolambda4AllSubmodules), that I will refer to.

1. in a multimodule android application (one android module and a java-only module), we must apply the [retrolambda gradle plugin](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) to all modules (app and java) that want to use java8 features

   - first the java module will be compiled by javac to java8-class files, retrolambda will convert them to java7 and a jar is built
   - then the app module will be compiled the same way as the java module: but now we get the apk instead of a jar: everything is java7 and can happily be used on Android 6
2. In my source code I have some unit tests, that deliberately use java8 code that should not work: I call `HashSet<>.stream()`

   1. Android studio and the Emulator: All tests work

      - I guess that Android Studio & Emulators do not even use retrolambda at all and just compile and run everything to java8
      - Is there a way to change that?: e.g. it would be good if any of the tests already catch these problems
   2. Gradle command line build:

      - `gradle clean app:test`: The unit tests work
      - `gradle clean java:test`: The unit tests fail
   3. I have no idea why the tests in the app module work and those in the java module fail: why is that?
3. On a real device with Android 6 everything crashes, as expected